# How do I find all references (i.e., dependencies, afferent couplings) to a Java class?

Tags: java, dependencies

Using Eclipse, I can select a class and list all references (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). I'm looking for a mechanism for the entire development team to obtain the same list of references from a central location, such as a SonarQube server.
When I drill down to a class on SonarQube, it shows me the number of afferent couplings. How can I find out what they are? I know it would take a huge amount of time/space for Sonar to generate that kind of report, but maybe there's a plug-in that can calculate that as requested (as per the execution of a Jenkins job).

Any suggestions of solutions that can be used to list the dependencies (afferent couplings) to a Java type in a given codebase would help.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html. Unfortunately, asking for such tools is considered off-topic here.

Comment: @vanje: So you have perfectly good answer, you give it to OP, and then you proceed to slam the question shut. Nice.  It is off topic only because you insist it is off topic, and enforce it with a close.  You don't have to become the Borg. (Readers: vote to re-open if you think this was unreasonably closed).

Comment: @Ira Baxter: What is your problem here? This question is off topic because of the Stack Overflow rules. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow ...". So I voted to close (and 4 others, too). This doesn't mean that this question is per se bad or not interesting. It's only off topic on this site. If you have problems with that, why don't you try to change the Stack Overflow rules instead of blaming me?

Comment: @vanje: You're one that voted to close it.  Usually that is followed by a dog-pile (as in this case).

Comment: @vanje: I removed the word 'tools' from the question. Please evaluate if that is acceptable and if so re-open the question. Otherwise, any constructive suggestions for the proper phrasing would be appreciated.  (JDepend is very helpful, but it gives you the efferent couplings at package level, not the afferent couplings at Java type level.)

Comment: @PauloMerson: You may want to submit this to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ which seems to be designed for tool questions.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I couldn't ask a question at softwarecs because I was not invited to join (maybe I missed some email invitation). In any case, I just flagged the question here at stackoverflow for moderator attention. As a matter of fact, I am not soliciting tool suggestions. One could have written a program or script that parses an entire Java codebase and builds the dependency graph pointing towards a given Java class. That person could share his/her solution in the answer. In any case, thanks a lot for your support on this.

Comment: @Paulo: see my bio, email to me your email address, I think I can get  you an invitation.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, we found, experimented with, configured, and just recently rolled out a solution to this problem for our entire Java development organization. Here's a summary of the solution:

- We have several java projects, broadly divided into libs and (web) applications.
- Applications can use different libs. The challenge was to find in our entire codebase all the callers of a given class/method/constructor in one of our libs.
- We use a continuous integration tool (Jenkins) that builds all libs and applications once a week off of the trunk for deployment (a sort of continuous delivery weekly deployment).
- We configured the jobs that run this weekly deployment to copy all generated jar/war/ear files to a specific server machine.
- On that server machine, we installed the [Dependency Finder tool](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/). This amazing free tool is the key to the solution. It can parse and extract **all** dependencies from the compiled code (in jar files for example). Then a user can query the tool about efferent (outbound) and afferent (inbound) dependencies. Most tools out there just give you the efferent dependencies.
- On that server machine, we automatically run a script that calls Dependency Finder to process (i.e., extract all dependencies from) all jar files shortly after they're generated once a week. Processing the entire code base takes less than an hour.
- On that machine, we also deployed to the local Tomcat a web application (war) that comes with Dependency Finder. (Dependency Finder comes with a GUI (Swt) client, a command line version, and a web UI version.
- We shared the URL to the Dependency Finder web interface with all developers.
- Using the web UI, anyone can quickly specify a query. To query all inbound dependencies to a given method in a class takes about 20 seconds.